# Percona XtraDB Cluster with HandlerSocket

Tags: mysql, percona, xtradb, handlersocket

The main question - is it possible to use HandlerSocket together with PXC? I've noticed that during high load writing socket crashes rather frequently with the error `HNDSOCK unlock tables: commit failed`.

Comment: Is there an error message associated with the crashes?  More information in general would be helpful.

Comment: The only string with error was near the end of logs:
HNDSOCK unlock tables: commit failed

Comment: For testing purpose I use 3 VMs, 2 of them with PXC and the 3rd with Galera Arbitrator. The script opens two connections for writing to both servers, writes about 100k rows to the first server, than 100k rows to another one and dies. After several executions HS's socket for writing disappears on one of the servers in nearly random manner and never reopened.

Answer (score 0):

I checked with our PXC developer, who said he hasn't tested HandlerSocket with PXC, but pointed out that there is an existing bug report where it crashes with handlersocket, "so safe
to say it is not supported with PXC." Yet, that is.  But you can check on the PXC forums to get the latest info - that is here he fields questions and the best place to message him. http://www.percona.com/forums/questions-discussions/percona-xtradb-cluster